# Pass some data to ITunes Store url and get it from application

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Is there any known way to pass some data in iTunes Store url:

`https://itunes.apple.com/app/id000000000?mt=8`

And then get it from installed app?

As I know, Google Play have "**referrer**" parameter that you can get from installed app, but iTunes doesn't. I need to track installations of our apps, and don't know where to start. Maybe there is a way to link our url and application launch?

Some companies, like [Adjust](https://www.adjust.com/) or [Appsflyer](https://www.appsflyer.com) can do that. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices here:

A) you can rely on [attribution measurement in Firebase/Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns). This is the way you are asking about. It's for free, but it has some huge limitations like only attributing some sources (no Facebook campaigns for example) and you need to use generally very unreliable UTM parameters with each link.

B) You can rely on AppsFlyer or Adjust which attributes referrer sources on the back-end. So it's agreement between Facebook / Google etc. and AppsFlyer to hand-over that information. It's industry standard and if you have money (you pay for each non-organic attribution, approx. 5 cents per install)